# database changes required while publishing asp.net website?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, iis

I made my first asp.net website. It has an sqlserver database.  When I publish it, do I have to make any changes to the database?  It works fine on my computer.

Comment: If you are not saving any machine related configuration in your database, then you do not have to make any changes

Comment: If your IIS and database are in two different servers, you may need to change the server property of your connection string.

Answer (score 0):

In most cases, no explicit changes are required for the database to work when website is published and hosted. Yes, you do have to make sure that the connection string points to the right server and right database. You can configure that in your `web.config` and also when the `Publish` dialog box opens up.

Run the `Preview` first before publishing directly. It will help bring out potential errors, if there are any during publishing stage so that you can resolve them before final publishing.

Answer (score 0):

Check your Connecting String in web.config.

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="DBConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=SQLSERVERNAME;Initial Catalog=DATABASENAME;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=USERNAME;Password=PASSWORD" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

replace with your details
1. SQLSERVERNAME
2. USERNAME
3. PASSWORD

hope this help.